# Matching an element in an unknown sequence location using structural pattern matching in Python 3.10

Tags: python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

Is there any clever way to match on an element in an unknown location in a sequence of unknown length using structural pattern matching in Python 3.10?

Below is a non-working example illustrating what I'd like to do.

```py
match [1, 2, "3", 4, 5]:
    case [*before, str() as str_found, *after]:
        print(f"Found string: {str_found}")
```

If you try to use a guard clause, the match isn't captured:

```py
match [1, 2, "3", 4, 5]:
    case [*elem] if any(isinstance(el, str) for el in elem):
        print("Found string, but I can't tell you its value.")
```

If the length is known, an or pattern could be used, though it's not pretty:

```py
match [1, 2, "3"]:
    case [*_, str() as str_found] | [str() as str_found, *_] | [_, str() as str_found, _]:
        print(f"Found string: {str_found}")
```

Based on answers and comments to other questions about structural pattern matching, I anticipate lots of responses informing me that structural pattern matching isn't the right tool for the job. I know my example doesn't showcase the benefit of using structural pattern matching for this as opposed to something like a simple for loop, but imagine parsing a nested dict and list structure resulting from a `json.load()`. In any case, my question isn't what the right tool is, but simply whether it can be done with this tool.

Comment: One makeshift option is to loop over the iterable directly, then `break` on `case` match. Your loop variable will then hold the matched item, and any extra assigned variables in the `case` statement will also be available. Not quite what you asked for, but what I came up with as a workaround (so for me the answer would be *no*, it's not possible with `match`/`case` alone, after playing around with `_` wildcards etc. as well).

Answer (score 0):

This is going to trigger some people, but here you go;

```py
match [1, 2, "3", 4, 5]:
    case xs if s:= next((x for x in xs if isinstance(x, str)), False):
        print("Found string", repr(s))
```